Question about part of JLPT N4
I am thinking about participating in either JLPT N5 or N4 and I am doing a test right now to see if I can do it, but really don´t understand this question here:
もんだい２: * に入るものはどれですか？　1，2，3，4から　一番いい　ものを　いとつ　えらびなさい。
2.1 かぜ * ____ ____ ____ 　なった
a) で
b) 出なく
c) こえ
d) が
I made a screenshot of this and the next two questions as well:

Can you help me understand this question? I am confused about the underscores and the word "いとつ", which is not even in the dictionary. Is it supposed to be "ひとつ"?
Thanks!
teha

Yes, it is ひとつ.

This exercise is confusing you because it is not really a single choice question, but an "order these items" question disguised as a single choice question.
You have 4 placeholders, 1 star * and 3 underscores ____, and 4 possible choices. All of the 4 provided choices must be used and placed in the corresponding placeholders in such an order that the sentence in your question makes sense.
Once you have figured out the correct order of the 4 provided choices, answer the test by picking the option that happens to be in the same position as the star * relative to the underscores ___.
for example, in your question 2.1, you need to figure out using your Japanese knowledge that the correct order of the 4 words is:

で　こえ　が　出なく

Because this produces a sentence that makes sense:

かぜでこえが出なくなった。

Then, since in your question, they are asking for the item that falls in the first placeholder (by putting the start * first and the 3 underscores after that: * ___ ___ ___), you pick the first item in your ordered list, i.e.:

で　こえ　が　出なく

Similarly, for your second example, the ordering that makes sense is:

うるさい　ランさん　を　立たせた


先生がうるさいランさんを立たせた。

For the second example, the star is ___ ___ * ___, so you pick
the 3rd item in your list:

うるさい　ランさん　を　立たせた


Ahhh I understood! Thanks so much! It wasn't easy to get in the first place imo. But it is clear now :-)

You're welcome. Your question is off-topic to be honest, but I encourage you to come back to this site if you have specific doubts regarding Japanese. This site has been very helpful to me specially when it comes to nuanced questions and very specific doubts that you would only typically be able to figure out by asking a teacher
